# Why Istio does not generate the following metrics for HTTP, HTTP/2, and GRPC traffic?

Tags: istio, istio-prometheus

Why Istio does not generate the following metrics for HTTP, HTTP/2, and GRPC traffic?

My Istio installation:

```bash
helm repo add istio https://istio-release.storage.googleapis.com/charts
helm repo update
kubectl create namespace istio-system
helm install istio-base istio/base -n istio-system
helm install istiod istio/istiod -n istio-system --wait
```

```
$ istioctl version
client version: 1.8.1
control plane version: 1.18.0
data plane version: 1.18.0 (10 proxies)
```

```
$ kubectl version --short
Client Version: v1.27.2
Kustomize Version: v5.0.1
Server Version: v1.27.2
```

```
$ helm version --short
v3.12.0+gc9f554d
```

```
$ helm list
istio-base  istio-system    1           2023-06-13 08:39:32.349599821 +0300 MSK deployed    base-1.18.0                     1.18.0     
istiod      istio-system    1           2023-06-13 08:39:34.034866006 +0300 MSK deployed    istiod-1.18.0                   1.18.0
```

**In documentation (https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/metrics/) wrote:**

```
For HTTP, HTTP/2, and GRPC traffic, Istio generates the following metrics:
Request Count (istio_requests_total): This is a COUNTER incremented for every request handled by an Istio proxy.
Request Duration (istio_request_duration_milliseconds): This is a DISTRIBUTION which measures the duration of requests.
Request Size (istio_request_bytes): This is a DISTRIBUTION which measures HTTP request body sizes.
Response Size (istio_response_bytes): This is a DISTRIBUTION which measures HTTP response body sizes.
gRPC Request Message Count (istio_request_messages_total): This is a COUNTER incremented for every gRPC message sent from a client.
gRPC Response Message Count (istio_response_messages_total): This is a COUNTER incremented for every gRPC message sent from a server.
```

But my Prometneus contains only TCP metrics:

```bash
istio_tcp_sent_bytes_total
istio_tcp_received_bytes_total
istio_tcp_connections_opened_total
istio_tcp_connections_closed_total
```

In my Prometheus config follow additional ScrapeConfigs:

```yaml
    - job_name: 'istiod'
      kubernetes_sd_configs:
      - role: endpoints
        namespaces:
          names:
          - istio-system
      relabel_configs:
      - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_service_name, __meta_kubernetes_endpoint_port_name]
        action: keep
        regex: istiod;http-monitoring
    - job_name: 'envoy-stats'
      metrics_path: /stats/prometheus
      kubernetes_sd_configs:
      - role: pod
      relabel_configs:
      - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_container_port_name]
        action: keep
        regex: '.*-envoy-prom'
```

Even despite the fact that I deployed `echo-grpc` according to this instruction https://istio.io/latest/blog/2021/proxyless-grpc/ these metrics are still missing in Prometheus.

Please tell me what is my mistake?